# Plotting huge number of locations on a map

Tags: google-maps, maps, data-visualization

Is there any good library that will enable to see the coarse location distribution.
I have some million data points to plot on a map. Doing it on google maps is going to be heavy. I want this to be like a dot plot.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/toomanymarkers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The closest I can think to the functionality you are looking for would be to implement a heatmap layer : https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/layer-heatmap.

This would allow you to see the distribution of points without plotting them individually and thus saving you some client-side work.

How well this will work with a million+ points however I am not sure. You might be best off looking into a fusion tables combination.